# Mapping With Restkit iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mapping, restkit

I am trying to map and store a response json data using restkit object mapping. unfortunately i cannot able to map a response data. when i view my database the datas are storing, but i get a crash with following message.. 
**this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key**

Output response

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "123456",
            "ne": "JohnSmith",
            "el": "example@example.com",
            "dob": "1985/02/04",
            "profile": {
                "id": "654321",
                "ht": "170cm",
                "wt": "70kg"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using mapping like this

```
 RKManagedObjectMapping *userProfileMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[GHSUser class] inManagedObjectStore:manager.objectStore];
    [userProfileMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"userId"];
    [userProfileMapping mapKeyPath:@"ne" toAttribute:@"name"];    
    [userProfileMapping mapKeyPath:@"el" toAttribute:@"email"];
    [userProfileMapping mapKeyPath:@"dob" toAttribute:@"dob"];

 RKManagedObjectMapping *standardProfileMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[GHSProfile class] inManagedObjectStore:manager.objectStore];

    [standardProfileMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"userId"];
    [standardProfileMapping mapKeyPath:@"ht" toAttribute:@"height"];
    [standardProfileMapping mapKeyPath:@"wt" toAttribute:@"weight"];

[manager.mappingProvider setMapping:standardProfileMapping forKeyPath:@"users.profile"];
```

//here in keypath(users.profile) i am getting crash,but profile details are inserting in db. when i change keypath to profile, i am not getting any crash but profile details are not inserting in db.

```
  [userProfileMapping mapRelationship:@"users" withMapping:standardProfileMapping];
```

Error Message:

* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_NSObjectID_48_2 0x888a8d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key profile.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your `users` parameter is an NSArray, not a NSDictionary. It doesn't know which `users.profile` to use.

You want to change the same line:

```
[manager.mappingProvider setMapping:standardProfileMapping forKeyPath:@"users.profile"];
```

to:

```
[manager.mappingProvider setMapping:userProfileMapping forKeyPath:@"users"];
```

and add this line to your userProfileMapping:

```
[userProfileMapping mapKeyPath: @"profile" toRelationship: @"profile" withMapping: standardProfileMapping]
```

Comment: Thanx for ur response. actually i want all datas in an array to be stored in db. I tried the last code already. but the profile data is not inserting in db. only users data are storing